# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Document not active

Tags: angular

I have a button that allows you to open a window in full screen mode. And there is a bug. If you click on the button and open the full-screen mode of the window. And then press the `ESC` button to exit full-screen mode and then press the button again, such an error will occur.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Document not active
>
> at FullScreenService.closeFullscreen

Is there any way to fix this error?

```
isOpenFullScreen: boolean;

fullscreen() {
  if (!this.isOpenFullScreen) {
    this._fullscreen.openFullscreen();
    this.isOpenFullScreen = true;
  } else {
    this._fullscreen.closeFullscreen();
    this.isOpenFullScreen = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that when you press the `ESC` button, the property `isOpenFullScreen` is not changed back to `false`. Try to use [`document.fullscreenElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/fullscreenElement) and change your `fullscreen` method as follows.

```
// isOpenFullScreen: boolean; // not needed

fullscreen() {
  if (document.fullscreenElement === null) {
    this._fullscreen.openFullscreen();
  } else {
    this._fullscreen.closeFullscreen();
  }
}
```

Maybe it's better to add a method to your service that indicates if you're currently in full-screen mode.

Comment: `The "fullScreen" property does not exist in the type "Window & typeof globalThis"`

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe `document.fullscreenElement` works

Answer (score 1):

I solved like this:

```
if (document.fullscreenElement) {
    setTimeout(() => document.exitFullscreen(), 1000);
}
```

Interesting, on 500ms, still throws the error, looks like some change in newer browsers versions, it's not enough to set it as 500ms.

Answer (score 0):

```
Angular 13
```

This is how I did it

```
 export class YourComponent implements OnInit {  
 
   elem: any; 
   isFullScreen: boolean;
 
   constructor(
     @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any
   )
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.chkScreenMode();
     this.elem = document.documentElement;
     this.elem.addEventListener('fullscreenchange',()=>this.chkScreenMode())
   }
 
  chkScreenMode(){
     if(document.fullscreenElement){
       //fullscreen
       this.isFullScreen = true;
     }else{
       //not in full screen
       this.isFullScreen = false;
     }
   }
 
 
   openFullscreen() {
     this.isFullScreen = true;
     if (this.elem.requestFullscreen) {
       this.elem.requestFullscreen();
     } else if (this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
       /* Firefox */
       this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
     } else if (this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
       /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
       this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
     } else if (this.elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
       /* IE/Edge */
       this.elem.msRequestFullscreen();
     }
     //this.chkScreenMode()
   }
 /* Close fullscreen */
   closeFullscreen() {
     this.isFullScreen = false;
     if (this.document.exitFullscreen) {
       this.document.exitFullscreen();
     } else if (this.document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
       /* Firefox */
       this.document.mozCancelFullScreen();
     } else if (this.document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
       /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
       this.document.webkitExitFullscreen();
     } else if (this.document.msExitFullscreen) {
       /* IE/Edge */
       this.document.msExitFullscreen();
     }        
   }
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).